# Why does DateTime.ParseExact format "dd MMM yyyy" throw exception if a single digit is sent

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to parse dates that are sent using the following format: `19 maj 2011`.

This can easily be parsed with `DateTime.ParseExact("19 maj 2011", "dd MMM yyyy", new CultureInfo("sv-SE"));`

However I can also get dates that are formatted like `1 maj 2011`.

This will throw a `System.FormatException` with message

> "String '1 maj 2011' was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

However if I use `d MMM yyyy` as format both `19 maj 2011` and `1 maj 2011` will work.

Comment: Parse the date as `"01 maj 2011"`

Comment: Because you told it to, drill sergeant.

Comment: @AndréSanson I don't control the other system

Comment: Then use `d MMM yyyy`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d       Represents the day of the month as a number from 1 through 31. A single-digit day is formatted without a leading zero
dd      Represents the day of the month as a number from 01 through 31. A single-digit day is formatted with a leading zero
ddd     Represents the abbreviated name of the day of the week (Mon, Tues, Wed etc)
dddd    Represents the full name of the day of the week (Monday, Tuesday etc)
```

Source: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm

Comment: Another useful link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN